# Increase time for executing queries in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm using a database on a remote server (Azure) to execute queries. When I use SQL Server, I don't have problems (sorry, I can't post an image yet):

[SQL Server](https://ibb.co/FHCJnNX)

But when I try to execute the same query in Azure SQL, the runtime reaches a limit and stops working:

[Azure SQL Server](https://ibb.co/12tJQHn)

My question is: how could I extend this runtime in Azure SQL?

Comment: Query editor is still a preview feature, why do you want to execute the query in it?

Comment: We don't actually need a picture, just the text of the query and the text of the error please.